# java.io.IOException: WebSocket method must be a GET

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, client, typesafe

I am trying to write a websocket client application where I got to subscribe for an websocket URL i am using `play-ws` for the same. But getting the exception like below.

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: WebSocket method must
>   be a GET

Dependency used:

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.4.0-M1"
```

Piece of code I used to get the websocket client is below,

```
trait PlayHelper {
  val config = new NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder(DefaultWSClientConfig()).build()
  val builder = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder(config)
  val wsClient = new NingWSClient(builder.build())

  def getBody(future: Future[WSResponse]) = {
    val response = Await.result(future, Duration.Inf);
    if (response.status != 200)
      throw new Exception(response.statusText);
    response.body
  }
}

object Client extends PlayHelper with App{

  def subscribe()={
    val url = "ws://localhost:8080"
    val body = getBody(wsClient.url(url).get())
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println(s"body: $body")
  }
  subscribe()
}
```

Exception screen shot is below:
[image]

Looking for the help for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `play-ws` supports websockets, you may want to use the `AsyncHttpClient` directly: https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client#websocket

Comment: I don't have any myself, last time I used `akka-http` to connect to as ws server